# Angular Resource calls and $q

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I have my code setup somewhat as below:

```
$scope.init = function(){
  return $q.all([resource1.query(),resource2.query(),resource3.query()])
            .then(result){
               $scope.data1 = result[1];
               $scope.data2 = result1[2];
               $scope.data3 = result[3];


               console.log(data1); //prints as [$resolved: false, $then: function]

               doSomething($scope.data1,$scope.data2); 
                 }
}
```

I was under the impression that the "then" function will be called only when all the resources get resolved. However this is not what I am seeing in my code. If I print data1, I get unresolveed.

Any clue as to what I am missing here ??

Comment: Does `resource1.query()`, etc. return a Promise? [`all`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q#all) expects an Array of Promises, and if they aren't Promises they will be considered immediately completed.

Comment: I am using angular 1.15 and it returns something like this [$resolved: false, $then: function]
I believe this is a promise

Comment: Please note that the indices in the result array are zero-based as would be expected of an array, so $scope.data1 = result[0], etc.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I ran into this problem, and it was quite confusing. The problem appears to be that calling a resource action doesn't actually return an http promise, but an empty reference (that is populated when the data returns from the server -see the return value section of [the $resource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource)).

I'm not sure why this results in .then(result) returning an array of unresolved promises, but to get each resource's promise, you need to use `resource1.query().$promise`. To re-write your example:

```
$scope.init = function() {
  return $q.all([resource1.query().$promise, resource2.query().$promise, resource3.query().$promise])
           .then( function(result) {
             $scope.data1 = result[0];
             $scope.data2 = result[1];
             $scope.data3 = result[2];

             console.log($scope.data1);

             doSomething($scope.data1,$scope.data2); 
           })
}
```

I hope that saves someone else some time.

Comment: This is really confusing and best I can tell not documented anywhere.  Without the ```$promise``` after the resource call I was getting an unfulfilled promise in .then which makes no sense.  Thanks for this.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer to this question.

Comment: result array begins with zero, so $scope.data1 = result[0] and so on is what you would want there.

Comment: Thank you!  This was driving me nuts today.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing data1 not $scope.data1

```
console.log(data1);
```

if i were you i would use it as follows

```
$scope.init = function(){
return $q.all([resource1.query(),resource2.query(),resource3.query()])
        .then(result){
          console.log(result[1]);
           $scope.data1 = result[1];
           $scope.data2 = result1[2];
           $scope.data3 = result[3];

           doSomething($scope.data1,$scope.data2); 
             }
}
```

Comment: @James Hans, did this fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like @cdidyks answer this utilises `$promise`, but in my opinion it is a better design pattern as it doesn't rely on all resources to be completed for assignment, and makes the $promises more accessible in less code.

```
$scope.data1 = resource1.query();
$scope.data2 = resource2.query();
$scope.data3 = resource3.query();

$scope.init = function() {
  return $q.all([
      $scope.data1.$promise,
      $scope.data2.$promise,
      $scope.data3.$promise
    ])
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log('all done');
      doSomething($scope.data1, $scope.data2);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those still trying to figure out a better way to go about this, try this:

```
  resource.query().$promise.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    // Do something else, like instantiate a JS driven table
  });
```